# Is it possible to get the domain from which a request was made with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express server that is serving as a middle-man for files stored in S3.

When a request is made to the server I want to determine the domain that the request originated from, serving a different file version based on the domain.

An example:

`www.example.com` has the inline script: `<script src="https://myserver.com/file/example.js" />`

Is it possible to know that `example.com` was the source of the request at the router-level?

Comment: Browsers generally send a [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header with every request. Your express server could get the domain from that

Comment: I thought that would be a good route to go down but `req.headers.referer` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@David784](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/117592258?noredirect=1) was correct in his suggestion. However, I needed to set the `referrerpolicy` attribute on my inlined script tag to `origin`. That solved the issue of `req.headers.referer` returning undefined.